# Chromecast disable tab casting

Tags: google-chrome, casting, chromecast

I'm looking for a way to disable the ability to cast the entire Chrome tab on a specific page? I've tried playing around with the chrome.cast namespace that the Chromecast Extension adds onto the window object in the browser but haven't found what I needed.

We are offering proper Chromecast support but have requirements to not allow casting a specific tab

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks!

Comment: As it turns out, if there is a Chromecast sender application on the page then that will be triggered when the icon near the address bar is used.

No need for anything else to happen.